# Eclipse Plugin Installation

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation

I want to install my pugine in eclipse without opening the eclipse. i have copied my plugin in plugin folder but by using this way i am not able to Uninstall plugin from eclise. When i am trying to uninstall plugin from "Eclipse Installation Detail" the Uninstall button is disable. i dont understand what is the proper way to install plugin without opening the eclipse. if is there any proper way then let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In latest versions of Eclipse (since Eclipse 3.4), a new provisioning mechanism appeared. You should never make any modification yourself in the Eclipse filesystem. You have to use p2 for manipulating your Eclipse installation.

Refer to the following links, for a first step in this install mechanism: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started

To manipulate things without launching the Eclipse itself:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_director_application

Answer (score 1):

If you manualy copy the plug-in in your Eclipse folder, then you are responsible for removing it. Since you didn't go through the Eclipse install mechanism, Eclipse is lacking the metadata needed to uninstall it. It basically says: "I see it is there, but I don't know how it got there, so better not remove it."

Answer (score 0):

check this out:
http://www.venukb.com/2006/08/20/install-eclipse-plugins-the-easy-way/

Comment: This is a quite old fashion way of doing it. This blog needs to be updated as lots of things had change since Eclipse 3.4 brought a new provisioning system called P2.